# What is the maximum records returned by Lookback 4 regardless of limit clause value?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, loopback4

In loopback 4, I know we can limit records like this

```
?filter={"limit":10}
```

but what is the biggest value I can set as limit? Also is there a value I can put there which is the same thing as getting all records? Things like 0 or -1 don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If limit is `undefined`, loopback will fetch all records.

Comment: do you mean like putting the literal string `undefined`? I'm looking for a string to put such that it gets all records.

Comment: On the code side, if the`limit` is `undefined` as a type, you can get all the data. But if you're on the request side, I have no idea other than removing the `limit` filter.